# Installing mysql2 gem with ruby 1.8.7 Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, macos, rubygems

I am currently trying to install the mysql2 gem, under Ruby 1.8.7 and Mac 10.6.6 and mysql 64 bits, so I can use Rails 3 and mysql together.

When I do the command:

```
sudo gem install mysql2
```

I get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed mysql2-0.2.6
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql2-0.2.6...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Result not known
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql2-0.2.6...
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Client not known
Enclosing class/module 'mMysql2' for class Result not known
```

I did a lot of things recommended for this problem here on SO, but nothing seemed to help.

Has anyone got a idea about what to do next?

Edit: When I try do to rake db:migrate, it says: http://pastebin.com/tuPwQmqL. I can't do rails server either.

Edit 2: Managed to do it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a warning that the documentation for a module is empty. It shouldn't cause any problems.

If you are able to your commands like "rake db:migrate" etc. Everything is fine  :)

Update: [http://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/mysql-5-5-snow-leopard-and-rails](http://freddyandersen.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/mysql-5-5-snow-leopard-and-rails/)/. This link should solve your problem. I faced the same problem on my other mac :)

Comment: The problem is, I can't do that. When I try do to rake db:migrate, it says: http://pastebin.com/tuPwQmqL. I can't do rails server either.

Comment: what does it say.. post it in the question

Comment: rake aborted!
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle
/Users/eduardo/Sites/rsps/Rakefile:4
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails 3, you should definitely be using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) and not doing sudo gem install anything. Add mysql2 to your Gemfile and just run `bundle`. That should install without any errors and let you run rake commands.